# R Syntax highlighting from knitr to ghost.io blog

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, ghost-blog

I am starting up a blog for R models and I currently use knitr and R markdown to produce documents. What I have tried to do is just copy the HTML from the the knitr output into the ghost.io blog, and it works perfectly with the exception of the code syntax losing its color.

Does anyone know a way to have my pasted HTML include the colored R code?

Comment: Can you use the html code produced by the output?

Comment: What operating system are you using?  On Windows, I can sometimes get this to work better by pasting into MS Word, then copying _THAT_ into my target.  I think Word supports many more clipboard formats, and so there seems to be a better chance of more faithful copying.

Answer (score 0):

Installing `Prism` to `Ghost` should enable syntax highlighting for multiple languages, including `R` and `html`

For the install instructions, follow this guide:

http://blog.davebalmer.com/adding-syntax-highlighting-to-ghost/